# Bootstrap affix always collapsing

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my HTML for navBar:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="195">
  <div class="container-fluid" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
    <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Aakarsh Madhavan</a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="dj">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="s">Skills</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="s">Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="f">Resume</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This however, isn't producing a normal response, it has the full navBar on the top originally, but when I scroll, the navBar changes in half. But it does not work properly, I've tried putting `affix` in other places, but it does not seem to work still?

Comment: Put it in codepen, It'll be easier to debug

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
 height: 10000px;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default {
    font-size: 22px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(87, 85, 85, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(87, 85, 85, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu #tag1 a{
    font-family: Chalkduster, Times, "Times New Roman";

}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(87, 85, 85, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(87, 85, 85, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);

}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    color: rgba(150, 90, 164, 1);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(87, 85, 85, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(87, 85, 85, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: rgba(150, 90, 164, 1);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #ffffff;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" data-offset-top="195">
<div class="container-fluid" data-offset-top="197">
    <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Aakarsh Madhavan</a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder"  data-offset-top="197">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="dj">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="s">Skills</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="s">Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="f">Resume</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! Appeared or removed? Please describe more! give me a screenshot if it is possible!

Comment: Sorry, I meant the black background has disappeared.

Comment: See: http://imgur.com/aNJpNRb and http://imgur.com/oE86gFA What black background you mean ?

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. I wanted the black background, but it has disappeard

Comment: Give me a screenshot, please!

Comment: Hmm! You could add this code easily See: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/25329/